# Как динамически менять значение input type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

С сервера приходит массив объектов, которыми заполняется табличка (код и скриншот ниже). Тип инпута ModuleValue по умолчанию text. Как сделать так, чтобы при получении значения module.param === work_mode тип инпута менялся на select и значение module.value становилось одной из его опций?

```js
<ModuleStatus>
Конфигурация: 
{modules.map(module => <Module key={module.param.toString()}>
   <ModuleParam>{module.param}</ModuleParam>
   <ModuleValue name={module.param} type='text' value={module.value} onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
   </Module>)}
   <PutNewConfigs type='submit' value='Сохранить изменения' onClick={this.putNewConfigs}/>
[![table][1]][1]</ModuleStatus>
```

[image: table]

Comment: продемонстрируйте пожалуйста, как вы пытались решить эту проблему

Comment: Пока нечего показать.